# Only allow year/month/day or year/month or year only?

Tags: php

I need to only allow:

- a year
- a year and a month
- a year and a month and a day

I should not allow:

- anything without a year
- a month by itself
- a day by itself
- a month and day
- a year and a day

I have written

```
if ($year && (($month && $day) || ($month && ! $day) || (! $month && ! $day)))
```

But it seems rather lengthy - is there a more concise way?

Comment: The condition looks fishy for me. What are the allowed values for these variables?

Comment: They will be `int` or `null`

Comment: @Progman having a $year and $day without a $month would pass

Comment: @Progman would not allow for a $year only without $month and $day

Comment: @panthro the problem with users commenting answers is that they trick the OP into believing they thought of the solution before someone else.  Whereas other people were actually coding up a solution/answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a KV diagram to find the expressions, which can be combined with `||` and simplify them. The KV diagram looks like this:

```
   |  Y | !Y |
---+----+----+---
   |  1 |  0 |  D
 M +----+----+---
   |  1 |  0 | 
---+----+----+ !D
   |  1 |  0 | 
!M +----+----+---
   |  0 |  0 |  D
---+----+----+---
```

Which results in two sub expressions `$year && $month` and `$year && !$day` like this:

```
($year && $month) || ($year && !&day)
```

And this can be simplified to:

```
$year && ($month || !$day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing helps with clearing up any uncertainly.

My interpretation of your input data is that your non-null values can never be zero.  The condition statement below will be making truthy/falsey checks -- this means that any encountered `0` values will be evaluated as falsey.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Y4n89))

```
if ($year && ($month || !$day)) {
```

- The `$year` value is required.
- If the `$month` also exists, then it's still good.
- If the `$month` does not exists, then `$day` must not as well.
  In other words, the `!$day` check is only executed if `$month` is not truthy.

Comment: If any of the variables can be `0` (zero) then you got problem. Comparing explicitly against `null` could be safer.

Comment: I hear you; I reckon its out of scope for this question though.

Comment: Sure, I still believe it's better to speak out the noticed problem and leave it open for OP to address, than to pretend there's none even you see one, hence my comment